# Problems migrating from flow14 to 23

Tags: vaadin-flow

I'm trying to migrate my project from Vaadin flow 14 to 23.
Everything was correctly compiled and add-orns where updated t compatible one.
I use Spring but NOT Spring Boot.
When I start my application in tomcat I get an error :

> GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> [com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners]
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application Lookup instance is
> not found in VaadinContext. The instance is suppoed to be created by a
> ServletContainerInitializer. Issues known to cause this problem are:
>
> - A Spring Boot application deployed as a war-file but the main application class does not extend SpringBootServletInitializer
> - An embedded server that is not set up to execute ServletContainerInitializers
> - Unit tests which do not properly set up the context for the test
>
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:54)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:48)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createPropertyDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:82)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer$StubServletConfig.createDeploymentConfiguration(ServletDeployer.java:185)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.lambda$getServletConfigurations$0(ServletDeployer.java:280)
>   at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)    at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.getServletConfigurations(ServletDeployer.java:279)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer.contextInitialized(ServletDeployer.java:194)
>   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:44)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

What's wrong ? What did I forget ?
Tks
Tullio

Comment: > A Spring Boot application deployed as a war-file but the main application class does not extend SpringBootServletInitializer <- Are you deploying as war? Does your main Application class extend SpringBootServletInitializer?